# Como configurar rota da Web Api para aceitar parâmetro nomeado(query string)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, route

Tenho uma web api com o seguinte método:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/documento/doc/list?{cpf}")]
 public string Listar(string cpf)
 {
      return "value";
 }
```

Preciso que o método acima seja chamado através da url:

> http://localhost:54037/api/documento/doc/list?cpf=53724435886

O grande problema é a "?" entre o list e o cpf.

Como eu posso alterar a rota para que funcione com a URL acima?

Comment: da maneira que vc sugeriu já testei e infelizmente não me atende. Essa web api é pra integração com um produto e precisa ter a URL: > http://localhost:54037/api/documento/doc/list?cpf=53724435886 A grande questão é justamente o list?cpf.

Comment: deixe sua rota somente assim api/documento/doc/list , que no final qnd vc passar a url api/documento/doc/list?cpf=53724435886 ele vai entender

Comment: Oi Jeferson, infelizmente não funcionou não. O Curioso é que mesmo a rota sendo [Route("api/documento/doc/list")] a url que funcionou foi: api/documento/doc/?cpf=53724435886.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defina a rota sem o "?", a query string será mapeada automaticamente para o parâmetro de mesmo nome.

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("api/documento/doc/list")]
 public string Listar(string cpf)
 {
      return "value";
 }
```

Comment: Agora foi!!! Muito obrigado. :)